Strictly decreasing function from an ordinal to $\mathbb{R}$
Context: We are working in $\mathsf{ZFC}$.
Problem: Given a poset $(P,<)$, let $\text{Dec}(P)$ be the set of all strictly decreasing function $f : \alpha \to P$, where $\alpha$ is an ordinal number.

For which ordinals there exists a function $f : \alpha \to \mathbb R$ strictly decreasing?
Determine $|\text{Dec}(\mathbb R)|$
Given $S := \{X \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb R) : |\mathbb R \setminus X| = \aleph_{0}\}$ ordered by the containment, determine $|\text{Dec}(S)|$.

About 1, the first thing to notice is that $\alpha < H(\mathbb R)$, where $H$ symbolizes the Hartogs number. I think a reasonable claim (since both naturals and $\omega$ itself work) could be that every ordinal below $H(\mathbb R)$ works, and from this conclude also that $|\text{Dec}(\mathbb R)| = |H(\mathbb R)|$.
Regarding 3, It's easy to show that there are at least $\aleph_0$ ordinals
which generate maps in $\text{Dec}(S)$ for example:
$$\omega \to \text{Dec}(S) : n \mapsto f_n := \begin{cases} X_0 = \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb N \\\\ X_{i + 1} = X_{i}\setminus\{\pi^{n+i}\} \end{cases}$$
but I don't have a clue for the upper bound. Any hint?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
